# Speeding up page loading of custom view

Tags: 7, views, ajax, taxonomy-terms

Right now I have a custom view template created where I have a left sidebar and a main content area.

In the left sidebar I have [taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) running to show my taxonomy terms.

I then have a custom view in my main content region filtering the nodes related to the taxonomy term. When I click on each term, the whole page has to load. It's just a bit too slow.

I've turned Ajax ON for my view, but it's not working (probably because I am not using it right).

Would using exposed filters be my answer to this? Or is there any way to keep my format and somehow pass the information to the views without having to load the entire page?

An example of a site doing what I would like can be found [here](https://soundcloud.com/explore/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) you can put a view in one area of the page and allow it to accept arguments given by clicking other elements on the page. [NodeOne's tutorial videos on Panels](http://nodeone.se/en/modules/panels) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion beth. I've thought about Panels, but have managed to design my site without using them and I don't necessarily want to start using them just for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to attach view filter "actions" to your menu items.  That way your view results will load with ajax.

this is probably the fastest way to do this, though I've never done it I think it's possible (theoretically).

Of course you could also just create Ajax functions that queried your view with the arguments when you click a menu item.

Comment: Thanks for the tips...if you can help me any further that would be great. I've done some preliminary searching and haven't found much.

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that effectively.

How familiar are you with PHP, Javascript, and Ajax?

Comment: Unfortunately, not very familiar. If it will take a lot of programming then this is something I can tackle later. I just thought there might be a way to do it in Drupal without all the coding. :(